# ColdFusion 10/11 metrics logging problems

Tags: coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

**Background Information**

I just recently started to get these errors with a production ColdFusion 10 server:

```
    Service Temporary Unavailable!

    The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

    Jakarta/ISAPI/isapi_redirector/1.2.32 ()
```

After spending a few hours with google I came across this thread on the adobe forums:

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1016323?start=0&tstart=0

There is a lot of information in this thread, but I focused on two areas.

1. Get current usage of threads/sessions/memory metrics.
2. Use the metrics information to tune the ColdFusion IIS Connector configuration

My goal was to finish with this blog post:
http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/tuning-coldfusion-10-iis-connector-configuration

The blog post was referenced in this reported bug:
https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3318104

**Problem**

I'm currently stuck on #1; getting current usage of threads/sessions/memory metrics.

I checked: CFadmin > Debugging & Logging > Debug Output Settings > Enable Metrics Logging.

ColdFusion 10 metrics.log:

```
    "Information","scheduler-1","07/20/14","15:12:24",,"Max threads: null Current thread count: null Current thread busy: null Max processing time: null Request count: null Error count: null Bytes received: null Bytes sent: null Free memory: 1055964040 Total memory: 1570766848 Active Sessions: 679"
    "Information","scheduler-1","07/20/14","15:13:24",,"Max threads: null Current thread count: null Current thread busy: null Max processing time: null Request count: null Error count: null Bytes received: null Bytes sent: null Free memory: 1136605536 Total memory: 1572864000 Active Sessions: 674"
    "Information","scheduler-1","07/20/14","15:14:24",,"Max threads: null Current thread count: null Current thread busy: null Max processing time: null Request count: null Error count: null Bytes received: null Bytes sent: null Free memory: 939095720 Total memory: 1572339712 Active Sessions: 673"
```

On a ColdFusion 11 development server I turned on Enable Metrics Logging just to see what it reported.  The metrics.log for that file looks like this:

```
    "Information","scheduler-1","07/20/14","15:20:59",,"Max threads: null Current thread count: null Current thread busy: null Max processing time: null Request count: null Error count: null Bytes received: null Bytes sent: null Free memory: 589971080 Total memory: 1320157184 Active Sessions: 40"
    "Information","scheduler-2","07/20/14","15:21:59",,"Max threads: null Current thread count: null Current thread busy: null Max processing time: null Request count: null Error count: null Bytes received: null Bytes sent: null Free memory: 583831160 Total memory: 1320157184 Active Sessions: 41"
    "Information","scheduler-2","07/20/14","15:22:59",,"Max threads: null Current thread count: null Current thread busy: null Max processing time: null Request count: null Error count: null Bytes received: null Bytes sent: null Free memory: 907572096 Total memory: 1431830528 Active Sessions: 40"
```

The problem is that almost all of the information is coming back as "null".

ColdFusion 10 environment:
Windows Server 2008 R2,
ColdFusion 10 Standard 64-bit,
Java 7u60

ColdFusion 11 environment:
Windows Server 2012 R2,
ColdFusion 11 Standard 64-bit,
Java 7u65

**Additional Note**

This was found in the coldfusion-error.log on ColdFusion 10 (not in CF 11 though):

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at coldfusion.server.jrun4.metrics.SimpleLoadMetric.run(SimpleLoadMetric.java:157)
        at coldfusion.scheduling.ThreadPool.run(ThreadPool.java:211)
        at coldfusion.scheduling.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:71)
```

**The Question**

Does anyone know how to get the Enable Metrics Logging to actually report threads used?
In the first link, "carl type3" posted a sample of his metrics.log file and it had all the information that I want to get.

**CF Admin Metrics Settings**

[image: ColdFusion 10/11 Metrics Settings]

ColdFusion 10 workers.properties:

```
    worker.list=cfusion

    worker.cfusion.type=ajp13
    worker.cfusion.host=localhost
    worker.cfusion.port=8012
    worker.cfusion.max_reuse_connections=250
    worker.cfusion.connection_pool_size=500
    worker.cfusion.connection_pool_timeout=60
```

ColdFusion 10 server.xml connector:

```
<Connector port="8012" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8445" tomcatAuthentication="false" maxThreads="500" connectionTimeout ="60000" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct port you need to set in the CF Admin can be found in the server.xml of cfusion.

In most setups with IIS as a frontend webserver it's 8012, so you need to change this setting in the CF Admin to this value.
Restart coldfusion and you should finally see some values with cfstat as well as in the metrics log.

Comment: For me, CF10 used 8012 and CF11 used 8014.

Comment: The 8012/8014 port is internal to ColdFusion. The same should not be used in CF Admin.

Comment: Setting this port to 80 did work.  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

To enable metric logging, go to **Debugging & Logging>Debug Output Settings** and then update the values highlighted below.

[image]

The "Max threads" shows null value in your logs, which further infer, that the metric logs are not enabled. Use the Current Thread Count as an input to the connection_pool_size and then set the max_reuse_connections. You will also need to add connectionTimeout and maxThreads in server.xml, as suggested in http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/coldfusion-11-iis-connector-tuning. This is applicable for CF10 as well.

Comment: I've updated my CF Admin to use 8501 for the "Connector Port" for cfstat (that was the only difference).  I rebooted the server and I'm still getting null for all of the thread metrics.  I've included information from my CF 10 server configuration in the question, the CF 11 server has the same values.  These values were in place before the reboot.

Comment: Also, thank you for the CF 11 IIS connector tuning link.

Comment: Change the port to 80 (port on which your webserver is running) and restart the CF Service.

In case, this doesn't work, then put it back to 8501, submit changes and restart the CF Service.